# Not able to disable comma in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the code where textarea will be created automatically. But i want to disable comma in this textarea,so i am using the below javascript function.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        var counter = 1;
        var val;
    
        $("#addButton").click(function () {
    
         var person = prompt("Please enter the Field name:", "");
         if (person == null || person == "") {
              
        return false;
           } else {
              
               val = person;
           }
    if(tabid == "menu4"){
     return false;
    }
     //alert(tabid);
       var newTextBoxDiv0 = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("class", 'form-group row')
        .attr("id",'form1ac' + counter);
       
        newTextBoxDiv0.after().html('<div class="col-xs-1"><input type="button" value="delete" onclick= rem(form1ac'+counter+')></div><div class="col-xs-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn"  name="" id="buttonl"  style="width: 170px;height:45px;background-color:#dcdcdc;color:black;">'+val+'</button><input type="hidden" name="buttonl" form="form1" value='+val+'></div><div class="col-xs-2"></div><div class="col-xs-4"><div class="form-group"><textarea form="form1" name="df" id="df" oninput = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[,]/g, "2")" ></textarea></div><input form="form1" type="hidden" name="tabid" value='+tabid+'></div>');
        newTextBoxDiv0.appendTo('#'+tabid);
        
        counter++;
         });
    
     
      
        
        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
         if(counter==1){
                  alert("No more textbox to remove");
                  return false;
               }
    
         counter--;
         
                $("#form1ac" + counter).remove();
    
             });
    
        
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea form="form1" name="df" id="df" oninput = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[,]/g, "2")" ></textarea>
```

The above jquery code will dynamically create new textarea with label option,which works perfectly. But i am trying to disable comma with the above mentioned javascript code which is not working perfectly.

Please help me!

Comment: *"which is not working perfectly"* - So what is it doing? Please [edit] your question to describe the desired behavior and the actual behavior. (Note that if you want to set the `.value` of the element as the user types that will tend to move the cursor to the end, which makes editing existing values very fiddly. The simplest solution is just to remove commas on `blur`.)

Comment: Please fix the alignment in your code, or better yet reduce it to the actual functionality you're trying to achieve - see [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please explain what "not working perfectly" means.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent user to type a comma:

```
<textarea class="no-comma"></textarea>
```

And

```
$(function() {
    $('textarea.no-comma').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 188 || e.keyCode == 110) { // thats a comma
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }).on('change input', function() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.html( self.html().replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'),'') ); // Remove all commas.
    });
})
```

Comment: That doesn't stop the user entering a comma via the clipboard or drag 'n' drop.

Answer (score 0):

Your html has a syntax error `"2")" >`

Should be `'2')" >`

`<textarea form="form1" name="df" id="df" oninput = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[,]/g, '2')" ></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

In place of below code

```
<textarea form="form1" name="df" id="df" oninput = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[,]/g, "2")" ></textarea>
```

use below code

```
<textarea form="form1" name="df" id="df" oninput = 'this.value = this.value.replace(/[,]/g, "2")' ></textarea>
```